# WMIC batch file to loop through CSV and get drive status

Tags: batch-file, csv, wmic

I am using this code to check the drive health status of remote PC's in my company

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in (C:\temp\HOSTNAMES.csv) do (
    WMIC /Node:%%a  DiskDrive GET Caption, Status
)
```

this works well but I need to capture the status i.e. (OK) or (Pred Fail) for each PC HOSTNAME on our network and build a simple .CSV report as there are over 2000 PC's to check

so the report would look like this

```
PC HOSTNAME  - STATUS
HOSTNAME01A  - OK
HOSTNAME02B  - Pred Fail
HOSTNAME03C   - Pred Fail
HOSTNAME04D   - OK
```

I am really struggling to assign the drive status to a variable so I can then build the report.

Comment: Append WMIC output to some text file. Then remove headers from this file using FIND /v

Comment: Hi Akina, thanks for your response, would you mind writing the code into my original code as I am very new to writing batch cmds and it will take me for ever using trial and error. thanks again.

Comment: The /NODE option also takes a file name as input. `wmic /node:@Hostnames.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

- `"tokens=1 delims= "` is the default and doesn't need to be expressed.
- When using wmic with the `/Format:csv` the node will be part of the output

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\30\SU_1371253.cmd
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

( for /f %%H in (HOSTNAMES.csv) do (
      Echo:Processing %%H>CON:
      for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
          WMIC /node:%%H DiskDrive GET Caption^,Status /Format:csv ^|findstr /i "%%H"
      ') do @Echo %%A
  )
) > "%~dpn0.Log"
```

Comment: Hi LotPings, thank you so MUCH for your response, if worked perfectly.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the output file is the same location and name as the batch but with the extension `.Log`

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by LotPings, the `csv` output format includes the node name. If we combine this with the hability of `wmic` to read the list of host from a file we can use

```
wmic /node:@"c:\temp\hostnames.csv" DiskDrive get Caption,Status /format:csv > report.csv
```

Or

```
wmic /node:@"c:\temp\hostnames.csv" /output:"report.csv" DiskDrive get Caption,Status /format:csv
```

Doing it in that way, we are starting only one `wmic` process instead of one for each node.